# When does `vec!` create different elements, or not?

Tags: rust

I just came across the following code in Rust:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec![HashMap::<i32, i32>::new(); 2];
    v1[0].insert(0,0);
    v1[1].insert(1,1);
    println!("{:?}", v1);
    
    let v2 = vec![Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::<i32, i32>::new())); 2];
    v2[0].lock().unwrap().insert(0,0);
    v2[1].lock().unwrap().insert(1,1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}

// outputs:
// [{0: 0}, {1: 1}]
// [Mutex { data: {0: 0, 1: 1} }, Mutex { data: {0: 0, 1: 1} }]
```

[link to rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1828f00cd739c77283fca8d296bb37b4)

It's apparently `v1` has 2 different HashMaps, while `v2` has only one. How's that happened? Shouldn't `v2` evaluates `Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::<i32, i32>::new()))` twice (like `v1` do) and thus create two different elements? Is it some kind of "lazy" evaluation somewhere?

Pardon my rust newbie question, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `vec![value; n]` syntax uses [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) to duplicate the value and fill up the vector. The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) even mention this kind of scenario:

> This will use `clone` to duplicate an expression, so one should be careful using this with types having a nonstandard `Clone` implementation. For example, `vec![Rc::new(1); 5]` will create a vector of five references to the same boxed integer value, not five references pointing to independently boxed integers.

Comment: The example from the documentation is a bit badly chosen. In case of something like `Rc<i32>` case the two scenarios will be completely indistinguishable because Rust will never allow you to mutate the number. (One might even consider sharing an _optimization_, akin to zero-sized types not incurring allocations.) `vec![Rc::new(Cell::new(1))]` would have been a better example because the difference would be observable by mutating the cell.

Answer (score 3):

The `vec!` macro clones value of the provided expression to fill the vector up to the requested length.

An `Arc` is a reference-counted smart pointer, which is shared by cloning. Each time you clone an `Arc`, it increases the reference count to the underlying data, but the underlying data is still the same.

So that's what is happening in your example. The elements of the vector are different pointers to the same `HashMap`.